# Strange case class syntax

Tags: scala, xpath

I've been learning Scala and decided to play with JSON parsing using json4s. I decided to use XPath syntax for deserializing and came across this strange bit of syntax I've never seen before.

```
val json = JsonMethods.parse("""{"meaningOfLife": 42}""")
val JInt(x) = json\"meaningOfLife"
```

The part confusing me is this bit right here

```
val JInt(x) = ...
```

I can't wrap my mind around what's happening there, I don't even know how to search this syntax or what it's called. Can anyone help me out? Scala is an amazing language with a lot of neat features that I'm not used to in other languages like C++ and Java.

**Edit**

To clarify, I'm confused because `x` isn't defined, but it's somehow being passed into a function or constructor then being assigned to the result of `json\"meaningOfLife"` which returns a `JValue`.

**Edit 2**

After some research and playing around, I figured out that this has something to do with case classes. I was able to run the following code.

```
case class MyCaseClass (x: Int)
val MyCaseClass(x) = new MyCaseClass(5)
println(x, x.getClass) // prints (5,int)
```

Which, after looking at some of the code, gives me a good understanding at what's happening.

```
val MyCaseClass(x) = MyCaseClass(5)
```

Is extracting (for lack of a better term) the `Int` value `5` from the instantiated `MyCaseClass` and storing that into `x`, meaning `x` will be of type `Int`.

In the code for json4s a `JInt` is a `JValue` which the `\` operator returns. So the `JInt(x)` is taking out a `BigInt` (stored in the class `JInt`) and putting that into the value `x` from what I gather.

But I still have a question. What is this process called? Is there any documentation on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "irrefutable pattern matching" and it's essentially equivalent to this bit of code:

```
val json = JsonMethods.parse("""{"meaningOfLife": 42}""")

val x = json match {
  case JInt(xMatched) => xMatched
}
```

In other words, any case class or any extractor that fits the pattern of the declaration's left-hand-side can be used in this way.

Addendum:

The "irrefutable" means that a `MatchError` will be thrown if the pattern cannot be satisfied.

Comment: I thought "irrefutable" meant it will always find a match at runtime, https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#irrefutable-patterns so `_` would be an example of an irrefutable pattern?

Comment: I think the spec might be talking more about irrefutable against a _type_, so a variable, a typed sub-class relation pattern or a constructor pattern which is (recursively) irrefutable in terms of its arguments..?

Comment: all pattern matches would throw `MatchError` if they don't match though right, by insuring something will always match (say a wildcard, or via a type patterns that's guaranteed to match) aren't we saying a "match" is irrefutable? i.e. You can not refute a match is inevitable?